# Symfony 2: get (default_locale) parameter from config.yml

Tags: symfony, locale, config, event-listener

Ok, I wan't to to something extremely simple, I just want to get this value from app/config/config.yml

framework:
  default_locale: nl

I want to get this value in an EventListener.. Can anyone help?

Edit 1: (is this right)? but i dont use the DependencyInjection classes here.. im confused..

services:
    core_locale.locale_listener:
        class: Eyee\CoreBundle\EventListener\LocaleListenerDefault
        arguments: ["%kernel.default_locale%"]

```
<?php

namespace Eyee\CoreBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;


/**
* use this class if no database Languages available..
*/
class LocaleListenerDefault implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $defaultLocale;

    public function __construct($default_locale = 'en')
    {    
        $this->defaultLocale = $default_locale;
    }`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 2):

I doesn't get what is your problem. To use an eventlistener you need to register the service in a service file. There you can pass argument to the constructor as you wrote above:

```
services: 
    core_locale.locale_listener: 
    class: Eyee\CoreBundle\EventListener\LocaleListenerDefault 
    arguments: ["%kernel.default_locale%"]
```

This should work.
Or what is your problem, what's not working there?

Answer (score 1):

it depends wether you have access to the container in your class.

In a controller you can do:

```
$locale = $this->container->getParameter('framework.default_locale');
```

There are numerous answers on stackoverflow that already answer this question.

For a non-controller class you need to use dependency injection.

Please read the documentation chapters [Introduction to Parameters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parameters.html).

Comment: But you can't access the service container outside a controller

Comment: That's not correct - you can access the container using dependency injection. you need to create a service definition for your class and inject it in there. Further you can inject just the parameter(s) you need into your newly created service.

Comment: If you provide more details about the class and it's purpose where you want to use the parameter i can add further information on how to accomplish your aim.

Comment: Like this?
services:
    core_locale.locale_listener:
        class: Eyee\CoreBundle\EventListener\LocaleListenerDefault
        arguments: ["%kernel.default_locale%"]

    private $defaultLocale;

    public function __construct($default_locale = 'en')
    {    
        $this->defaultLocale = $default_locale;
    }

I don't use 

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

here..

Sorry for the markup.. Stackoverflow doesnt allow to make a 'clean'  reply ?